# how to make the screen command console open after showing output mine is closing very fastly . but without using Console.ReadLine();

Tags: c#, .net

how to make the screen command console open after showing output
mine is closing very fastly .
but without using Console.ReadLine();

Comment: Sounds like a perfect [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you  don't want to use `Console.ReadLine()` for some reason, you can use `Console.ReadKey()` or perhaps `Thread.Sleep(10000)`.
The screen stays for 10 seconds